# Iterating over a list of BS4 Tag elements to delete specified text

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

So I did some scraping and the result is a list of lists, each element from the list is BS4 Tag type and I cannot find a way to remove the `<li>` and `</li>` from it.
Code:

```py
for page in url_lst:
    page = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    match = find_by_text(soup, 'The GAP', 'li')
    all_matches.append(match)
print(all_matches)
```

Output:

```
[[<li>
  The GAP Group, GAP – groups, algorithms and programming, version 4.10, Available from http://www.gap-system.org, 2018. 

</li>], [<li>
  The GAP Group, <span class="MathTeX">$GAP$</span><script type="math/tex">GAP</script> groups, algorithms, and programming, version 4.4.12 (2008), http://www.gap-system.org. 

</li>], [<li>
  The GAP Group, (2008). (http://www.gap-system.org). <span class="it">GAP–Groups, Algorithms, and Programming, Version 4.4.12.</span>
</li>], [<li>
  The GAP Group, 2019. GAP – Groups, Algorithms, and Programming, Version 4.10.1; https://www.gap-system.org. 

</li>]]
```

All I really need is to remove the `li` bits in the beginning and the end of every item.
The types:

```
print(type(match))
print(type(all_matches))
print(type(match[0]))

<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

I need to iterate over all results and remove the `<li>` bits so I can transform the rest into .csv and continue working. I tried .strip and Regex but nothing works because they are BS4 Tags, not strings. I tried to convert the whole thing to string, which worked as I managed to remove the  `li` bitd using regex, but then I cannot use the string to convert to pd.dataframe. Can anyone think of a solutuon to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `text` with `strip`(if extra space present )

```
for i in all_matches:
    print(i[0].text.strip()) # i am assuming there is one `li`tag present list so i am using direct indices 0 if not you can loop that also
```

Comment: That seems to work like magic, thanks a lot ! I do not understand it though, how can it work if  I am not even specifying ```<li>``` anywhere ?

Comment: valid question. Thanks Segey for raising this thread and for giiving all of us some learning options. Very well done! Thanks also to you gaurov